# JSON Params being sent as empty string instead of nil in Specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

Converting an app from Rails 4 to Rails 5. Everything is going well, though it seems this line is causing an issue. In Rails 4, it was:

```
get :show, token: user.token, email: user.email
```

With Rails 5, the syntax is:

```
get :show, params: { token: user.token, email: user.email }, format: :json
```

The problem in this case is that `user.token` is `nil`. Under Rails 4, the controller received the params as such:

```
{"token"=>nil, "email"=>"johndoe1@...", "action"=>"show"}
```

With Rails 5, now some tests are failing as the `token` is received as:

```
{"token"=>"", "email"=>"johndoe1@...", "action"=>"show"}
```

How can I get Rails 5 to respect it is `null` and not an empty string?

I don't know if this will affect `get`s outside of spec but I cannot find any solution to this. I tried `as: :json`, as well as `format: :json`, and even `to_json`, and nothing.

Thank you